# Server Send Out message from one client to all Clients conneted. JAVA

Tags: java, client-server

I am writing a Server/Client chat where basically Multiple Clients connected to One Server. One client send a message to server Then all other Clients will get the same message. For example: Client A, B, C Connected to A same Server. Client A send Message To Server, Server then will send the same message to client B and C but exclude Client A.

I'm stuck at part where Server send out the message to all other clients.

Below is the code, I'm just a Java beginner so any help with the code will be much appreciate.

ServerSide

```
public class ServerP2P extends Thread{
private ServerSocket server = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
private ArrayList<ServerThread> clientThreadList = new ArrayList<>();
private int maxClient = 4;
private int port = 9990;
boolean listening = true;

    public ServerP2P(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Server with Port "+port+" is Up and Running");
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Room Chat Is Up");
        while(listening){
            for(int i = 0;i<clientThreadList.size();i++){
                if(!clientThreadList.get(i).getConneection()){
                    System.out.println(clientThreadList.get(i)+" is removing from server because there is no conntection");
                    clientThreadList.remove(i);
                }
            }
            try{
                clientSocket = server.accept();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("User with IP "+clientSocket.getInetAddress()+" Has Connected to Server");
            clientThreadList.add(new ServerThread(clientSocket));
            try{
                Thread.sleep(200);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<ServerThread> listOFClient(){
        return clientThreadList;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ServerP2P server = new ServerP2P();
        server.start();
    }
```

}

ServerThread

```
 public class ServerThread{
private Socket clientSocket;
private boolean connected;
private Incomming incommingData;
String msg = null;

    private class Incomming extends Thread{
        private DataInputStream input;
        public void run(){
            try{
                input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("User with IP "+clientSocket.getInetAddress()+" has connected");
            while(true){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    int msgSize = input.readInt();
                    byte[] msgByte = new byte[msgSize];
                    for(int i = 0; i < msgSize ; i++){
                        msgByte[i] = input.readByte();
                    }
                    msg = new String(msgByte);
                    System.out.println(msg);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ServerThread(Socket newClientSocket){
        this.clientSocket = newClientSocket;
        connected = true;
        incommingData = new Incomming();
        incommingData.start();
    }

    public boolean getConneection(){
        return connected;
    }
    public void closeConnection(){
        try{
            connected = false;
            clientSocket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

ClientSide

```
public class ClientP2P{

private  Socket serverSocket = null;;
private  DataOutputStream output = null;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        System.in));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientP2P client = new ClientP2P();
    client.startConnect();;
}
public void startConnect(){
    int port = 9990;
    try {
        serverSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
        System.out.println(serverSocket.isBound());
        output = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your name: ");
        String nameClient = reader.readLine();
        output.writeInt(nameClient.length());
        output.writeBytes(nameClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("You Are Connected");
    System.out.println("Chat Can Start");
    sendText();
}
public void sendText(){
    try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Type Message: ");
            String msg = reader.readLine();
            output.writeInt(msg.length());
            output.writeBytes(msg);
            System.out.println("Message sent");
            recivedText();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void recivedText(){
    try{
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
    int textSize = 0;
    while(input.available() != 0){
        byte[] byteString = new byte[textSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < textSize;i++){
            byteString[i] = input.readByte();
        }
        String txtServer = new String(byteString);
        System.out.println(txtServer);
        textSize = 0;
    }
    sendText();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks For Your Time Guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServerThread` receives the messages and you want to send them to all other clients. One way you could achieve is to have the clients register themselves with the Server (this would help in the server not knowing the clients when it starts, which ideally should be the case). In your ServerThread, get a list of available clients from the server and loop through them and send the message to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use ObserverDesign pattern to hold the list of all your buddy/user to whom you wish to send message. Use HashMap to maintain a list of all the observer and its socket. Once the message is received, you retrieve the sockets of each user and write the same message on each socket.